# Mass Effect 3 console cheats?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I am playing Mass Effect 3 and I used console cheats to get all items. I used giveall and giveallarmor. But when I go to equip them in the bench where guns can be modified or where we change the armors there is nothing beside which I have got by genuine means. So where does these inventory items go? If I use giveallarmor code where do these armors go. Are there only 8 armors? Cause I have only unlocked 8 of them but using cheats there is nothing. Do I have to buy these items. Same goes with supergun and superarmor. Also can someone give me the details on how these codes work after entering them in the console. As I can increase my reputation but when I tried to get spectre talents where can I get them after entering the cheats. Please I am new to this game.

Answer (score 1):

Command line cheats are not the best way to cheat with mass effect 3. For a start a lot of times you will lose anything you enter when you exit the game or restart your computer.

The best way to get talents and various points and money in the game is to use a coalesque editor which edits your game save, this is the standard way to cheat is ME3

http://wenchy.net/me3-coalesced-utility/

This is the most user friendly client to use to start with.

To find alternatives you can look [here](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks_(Mass_Effect_3))
 I personally use Gibbed.

Once in it is just a case of looking for what you want to change and just changing the value, this is really simple in the various utils.

Hope this helped.

**Further Info**

> Yes, the super gun and super armor are cheat only items.
>
> As TopperFalkon said, the highest level normal game weapons and armor
>   are the Spectre gear weapons, unlocked for purchase from the C-Sec
>   Requisitions Officer in C-Sec academy and through the Normandy's
>   requisitions officer once you have gotten an achievement which
>   requires you to have a certain large amount of money at one time.
>   [Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/944902-mass-effect/answers/59763-super-gun-cheat-only)

You could also try a trainer cheat for the game which can be found here http://m0001.gamecopyworld.com/games/pc_mass_effect_3.shtml#Mass Effect 3 v1.5 (v1.5.5427.124) +12 TRAINER 2

This gives quick key cheats instead of command line and might have what you need

Comment: Nope it's difficult to edit. Also cannot get supergun and superarmor with it. I have tried it.

Comment: which util are you using?

Comment: @Hunter what i can confirm though is that anything entered into console is temporary there is no way to fix that

Comment: edited answer with some more information for you @Hunter

Answer (score -1):

It takes a large amount of skill to edit it and I strongly suggest against it and just play the game as it isc because as far as it goes the games pretty easy